# Ruby initialize method: setting instance variable with a hash key

Tags: ruby, hash, initialization

I am facing a undefined local variable or method error when initializing the following in ruby:

```
 class Model
  attr_accessor :var1, :var2, :state
  def initialize (x, y, key)
    @var1 = x
    @var2 = y
    @state = every_state[:key] #this line produces the error

  @every_state = {
  :A => SateA.new,
  :B => StateB.new,
  :C => StateC.new,
  :D => StateD.new
  }       
  end

  def select_state(key)
    every_state[:key]
  end
end
```

When I am using the class like

```
model = Model.new(1,2,:A)
```

The error occurs: *undefined local variable or method `every_state'*

As I am new to ruby coming from a java background, I wanted to pass a key to the initialize method (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483749/state-design-pattern-from-java-to-ruby)), to select a specific initial state from the hash.

Could it be that I am using the hash in a wrong way, or should I take it out of the initialize method completely and use another method to set it? My other thought is that I am using the symbol for key incorrectly.

Also, is there a direct implication of operating on non-instance variables within the initialize method? For example I was wondering what is the purpose of declaring the hash as an instance variable within initialize...

Any ideas are very welcome.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong - `@every_state` is defined in `#initialize`, and thus should be indented at the same level. Also, you should initialize `@every_state` before using it - move the initialization before the call (`@state = ...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this implementation is the closest one to the Java one.

```
class Model
  attr_accessor :var1, :var2, :state

  def initialize (x, y, key)
    @var1 = x
    @var2 = y
    @every_state = {
      :A => SataeA.new,
      :B => StateB.new,
      :C => StateC.new,
      :D => StateD.new
    }   
    @state = select_state key 
  end

  def select_state(key)
    @every_state[key]
  end
end
```

Comment: That works, thanks for the help. However I am still wondering about ennuikiller's remark: How can I avoid redefining the hash with every call to Model.new ?

Comment: Note that the latter version is different than the original Java version. The latter version shares the states with all instances (If you modify State A in instance X, it also gets modifies that state A of instance Y).

Comment: So, now that the hash is defined as a constant, it is shared among all instances of Model.

Each model carries the entire hash and also has an instance variable @state. @state selectively takes a value from the hash depending on the business logic. This *should* vary between different model objects, right?

If the original constant hash with the states change, then the change will propagate to all model objects, right? So by saying "shares the states with all instances" you mean shares the hash which is now a constant across all models? -- but not the value of the @state in each of them.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still a bit confused: we modify the @state variable by taking any value from the States hash right? Is that what you mean?

The way I understand it is that @state is instance-specific, but the States hash, which is now a constant, is tied to the class, thus shared among all instances. I hope this is correct. Perhaps I should read up on the clone method..

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation. The idea was for a Model to store its available states in a hash structure. All subsequent model objects should share the same available states.

@state is a variable which references an object from the available states hash based on some business logic. Each state object in the hash has actions which may or may not change the @state of that particular instance.

So @state is instance specific, but the hash structure, which can be defined as a constant, is tied to the class? -- Still some confusion.. Sorry about all the questions.

Comment: I have rolled out the update after reading the Java code carefully cause it's not what you want. Back to your first question, the redefinition here has no side effect. I believe ennuikiller's remark is not valid in this context.

Comment: ...so it makes no difference where I define the hash? Inside the initialize method as an instance variable, or at top level as a constant..

Comment: In ruby, defining the constant inside the class body(top level) will make it class constant, like doing public static final in Java, and following this approach will make us share the state as hrnt noted above. That's not what you want for sure and that's why I represented the states as instance variable instead.

Comment: Well, actually that is what I had in mind... Could it be that my java example is wrong then, based on my comments above?

Comment: No it's ok, but if you turned the everyState constant to a normal field then you will have the same code as Ruby's one.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a function called "`every_state`". You only have a instance variable `@every_state`. That is why you get an error.

Replace all calls to `every_state` with `@every_state`. You don't have a function or a local variable `every_state`. You only have a instance variable `@every_state`.

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo: :A => SateA.new  should be :A => StateA.new.  Also I would put the hash definition at the top level outside of the initialize method otherwise you'll be redefining it with every call to new which is definite;y NOT want you want to do!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, however would you mind explaining a little further. I put the has definition outside of the initialize in a separate method:

def getStates
   available_states = {
    :A => SataeA.new,      
    :B => StateB.new,      
    :C => StateC.new,      
    :D => StateD.new    
    } 
  end

Wouldn't that still redifine the hash members each time? Thanks

Comment: You are still spelling state wrong, `SataeA` needs to be `StateA`.

Comment: I believe he wants to maintain a set of states for each individual instance, that's why i think the hash definition is ok as it's now.